# jackson assign default value of a property is missing

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, default-value

Is there any way to assign default value when a property is missing in Json file while deserializing JSon using Jackson

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Sample {

    private String value = "hai";

   /* public Sample(String value) {
       this.value = value; // when I remove @AllArgsConstructor and  uncomment this constructor ,the default value is assigned if the property is missing in Json file
    }*/ 
 }
```

Comment: Is Jackson a good library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not do anything for this,

```
class Student {
  public String course = "MATH";
}
```

If `course` value is missing from the JSON, the value in the bean will by default set to MATH.

Comment: NO , the value is actually returned as null

Comment: @Priya Post your JSON structure and the output.

Comment: @Priya It can be null only in the case if the JSON is explicitly setting the value of this property to null, but that you didn't ask for.

Comment: I have edited my Question

Comment: @Priya It can be due to jackson version it it's jackson 2.10 then, for missing properties jackson will replace with null, even if we set default value in `Student` calss